# What are the electrical requirements of the antennas used in Starlink?

Tags: antenna, starlink

My interest is in both the antenna for the ground segment (the "UFO on a stick") and the antennas for the space segment (phased arrays if I'm not mistaken).

I couldn't find around much more of a general description, do you know where i can find more details? (patent or publications)

Comment: I'm no expert, but here's a start on the patent search: https://patents.google.com/?q=antenna&assignee=Space+Exploration+Technologies+Corp.&patents=false Patens will usually try to cast a wide net for specifications, they won't narrow them down to specific values if they don't have to, because (all else equal) their value can often be greater when they are broader (up to some limit). However the individual claims within the patent might get more specific, but every time I try to read a modern patent I end up looking like this: @@

Comment: Companies that spend a lot of money in development of an antenna may prefer to hide details and exact data.

Comment: This is what I found they use energy from solar panel they have and exect energy requirement maybe hidden to us. Check out this maybe helpful https://bitactro.com/starlink-internet/#Features_Of_Starlink_Satellites